# Return rows of df of particular month and year python pandas OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, stringindexoutofbounds

I am trying to create a function that will return rows pertaining only to particular month and year:

**df**

```
order_date      Type
2015-01-01      A
2017-09-01      A
2016-12-19      C
2019-11-23      D
2018-10-29      B
2017-12-31      B
2015-11-30      A
2015-08-30      B
2015-09-24      D
2015-01-27      E
```

**Defining function**

```
def return_data_month_year(month, year):
    month = pd.to_datetime(month).month()
    year = pd.to_datetime(year).year()
    df = df[((df['order_date']).dt.strftime('%B') == month)&((df['order_date']).dt.strftime('%Y') == 
    year)]
    return df
```

**Calling function**

```
  return_data_month_year('Jan','2015')
```

Expected output:

```
order_date      Type
2015-01-01      A
2015-01-27      E
```

**I am getting error(Output):**

```
   OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call `month = pd.to_datetime(month).month()` and `year = pd.to_datetime(year).year()`.

Also `'%B'` returns full month name, eg. `January`. To return only abbreviation (`Jan`, `Feb`, ...), use `%b`:

```
def return_data_month_year(df, month, year):
    return df[((df['order_date']).dt.strftime('%b') == month)&((df['order_date']).dt.strftime('%Y') == year)]

# to convert column 'order_date' to datetime:
df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime( df['order_date'] )

print( return_data_month_year(df, 'Jan','2015') )
```

Prints:

```
  order_date Type
0 2015-01-01    A
9 2015-01-27    E
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
 error i got

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor Seems that column `'order_date'` is not of time datetime. See my edit how to convert it.